# Atari 1040 STFM power supply issue & high-pitch noise

Tags: atari, power, atari-st

I have an Atari 1040 STFM that's been sitting in the basement for about 30 years. It doesn't power on. The power indicator light is not illuminated and there's a high-pitch noise coming from the power supply. The power supply looks great -- nothing looks out of the ordinary. Any suggestions on what to look for? Can the supply be replaced?

Comment: Either the supply itself is faulty, or the supply is OK but a fault in circuitry it powers such as short circuit makes the supply emit noise.

Comment: And the first step is to check all capacitors. Most of the time it's [failed capacitors](https://www.google.com/search?q=failed+capacitors).

Comment: Power supplies (rather the coils in there) tend to whine when the load exceeds their maximum - You shouldn't keep that thing switched on for too long. Very likely, the fault isn't even on the power supply, but rather on the main board of the ST - And again, very  likely, it's caused by a shorted cap.

Comment: Have you measured the output on the PSU to see that the voltages are within spec?

Comment: The good news is there's both cap kits for the PSUs and replacement PSUs available should you need one. Exxos is a source in the UK.

Comment: When the PSU is plugged into the main board, the 5V and 12V read 0. Unplugged it reads 5V and 12V. I'll take the ST apart a little more and examine the main board.